# no puedo guardar url de una imagen subida al storage en la database firebase

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, firebase, web

estoy haciendo un sistema con Firebase pero estoy comenzando recien he estado viendo la documentacion de firebase y bueno no sé en que puedo estar equivocado, he provado con varios codigos y me sale el mismo error siempre.
tengo un problema al momento de registrar la URL en la database me tira un error 
la imagen se guarda bien en el storage

solo estoy trabajando con javascript

Hola a todos, estoy haciendo un sistema con Firebase pero estoy comenzando recien he estado viendo la documentacion de firebase y bueno no sé en que puedo estar equivocado, he provado con varios codigos y me sale el mismo error siempre.
tengo un problema al momento de registrar la URL en la database me tira un error 
la imagen se guarda bien en el storage

solo estoy trabajando con javascript

[image: este es el error que me sale en el navegador]

les dejo mi codigo para que le echen un ojo

```js
function guardaar(downloadURL){
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  var timeStamp = () => {
    let options = {
      month: '2-digit',
      day: '2-digit',
      year: '2-digit',
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute:'2-digit'
                  };
    let now = new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', options);
    return now;
      };
    noti = {}
    noti.titulo  =$("#Titulo").val(),
    noti.subtitulo  =$("#Subtitulo").val(),
    noti.info = $("#Info").val(),
    noti.precio =$("#Precio").val(),
    noti.fecha =timeStamp(),
    noti.foto = downloadURL;
    noti.miId  =user.uid

  var ref = firebase.database().ref('ventass');
  ref.push(noti);
  animation();
  })
}


var storage = firebase.storage();


$("#foto").change(function () {
  readURL(this);
});

$("#ImagenPreview").click(function(){
  $("#foto").trigger("click");
});


var selectedFile; 
function getfile() {
    var pic = document.getElementById("foto"); 
    selectedFile = pic.files[0]; 
    document.getElementById('submit_link').setAttribute('disabled', 'true'); 
    myfunction(); 
} 
function myfunction() {
    var name="123"+Date.now(); 
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/images/'+ name); 

    // firebase  
    var uploadTask = storageRef.put(selectedFile); 
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){ 
      var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100; 
        document.getElementById("barra-de-progreso").style.width = progress + "%";
        switch (snapshot.state) { 
          case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: 
            console.log('Upload is paused'); 
            break; 
          case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: 
            console.log('Upload is running'); 
            break; 
        } 
        document.getElementById("progreso").className="d-none d-lg-block";
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error); 
      },function() { 
         uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then( 
          function(downloadURL) { 
          console.log('url del archivo', downloadURL); 
        document.getElementById('submit_link').removeAttribute('disabled'); 
      }); 
    }); 
}; 

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('#ImagenPreview').attr('src', e.target.result);
      }
       reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                    <input type="text" id="Titulo" class="form-control" placeholder="Titulo">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <input type="text" id="Subtitulo" class="form-control" placeholder="Subtito">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <input type="text" id="Info" class="form-control" placeholder="Info">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <input type="number" id="Precio" class="form-control" placeholder="precio">
                  </div>
                   <img id="ImagenPreview" class="img-thumbnail" src="img/defaul.jpg" style="width:10%;height:auto;"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-lg-none " id="progreso">
                    <div class="progress">
                      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-warning" role="progressbar" style="width:0%" 
                      id="barra-de-progreso" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                <div class="input-group" style="display:none;">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i></span>
                  <input type="file" id="foto" class="form-control file" name="mainimage" 
                  value="" onchange="getfile()">
                </div>
                  <button type="button"  id="submit_link" onclick="guardaar();" class="btn btn-success btn-fill guardar">Publicar<div class="ripple-container"></div></button>

              </form>
```

Comment: para guardar no tienes que hacer [`ref.set(noti)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data)?

Comment: hola @JackNavaRow tambien lo intente con  [ref.set(noti);] pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: en el evento onclick tienes la funcion `guardaar()` y el espera el parametro `downloadURL` y no lo estas enviando por tanto coloca `undefined` alli esta el error

Comment: raioz amigo no entendi bien sorry, entonces como puedo pasar el parametro dentro la funcion guardaar() o no es así? -_-*

Comment: tienes que declarar la variable `downloadURL` global , es decir  , al inicio del JavaScript, luego debes quitar la declaracion de la variable de la funcion; y con todo eso creo que funcionara

Comment: ya lo encontre amigo gracias, la solucion fue esta:
primero en el html, la funcion getfile() lo pase a la parte del button donde estaba la funcion guardaar(); lo reemplace!
despues en la parte de js, en la funcion de myfunction(); deja la funcion guardaar(); asi como esto.
mira
uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then( 
            function(downloadURL) {
              guardaar(downloadURL); 
y bueno ahora anda todo bien, espero que hayas entendido. saludos !!

Comment: genial!, y que tal si responde tu pregunta , los usuarios activos del sitio podrian premiarte